# postgres db backup is small after crontab

Tags: postgresql, cron

I'm trying to do a simple postgres backup with crontab. Here is the command I use:

```
# m  h  dom mon dow user     command
 49 13  *   *   *   postgres /usr/bin/pg_dump store | bzip2 > /home/backups/postgres/$(date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d")_store.sq.bz2
```

A backup file is created but it is very small (looks like 14 bytes).

I can run this command just fine in the terminal (with a filesize that matches my db).

The log files don't mention any errors (grep CRON /var/log/syslog). Any idea what might be off?

Comment: Can you try outputting what the command `/usr/bin/pg_dump store` returns from the cron job? May be that the environment that cron runs under is making the command fail not returning what you're expecting into the shell pipe.

Comment: 1) unable to connect to database 2) Maybe bzip2 is not in the path 3) cron overrun

Comment: @wildplasser may be onto something. Cron runs on a very restricted shell  and `bzip2` may not be in the PATH for the shell cron is running under. I'd break the commands apart and ensure each of them run successfully individually in cron.

Comment: 14 bytes is the size of an empty bzip file -- try creating a file length 0 and bzipping it -- 14 bytes.  On an Ubuntu 14.04 system, the cron job you list works without any changes -- I would also check filesystem permissions and make sure it works without the date command (just a set filename to the postgres user directory).

Comment: A couple other things to consider: Piping can "eat" status codes without the explicit use of `PIPESTATUS`, which I doubt *cron* uses, and `bzip2` is only having its stdout redirected, not its stderr as well.

Comment: BTW: is this the **master** crontab ?

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution of this, is to realize is that running the 'same' command in bash and running via Cron **isn't the same thing**!

For e.g. when run via Cron obvious defaults (.bash_profile / .pgpass / default binary paths) aren't the same and thus what works on bash may not work in Cron.

For a checklist:

1. Ensure Bzip2 is replaced with the complete path (for e.g. `/usr/bin/bzip2` on CentOS / RHEL)
2. Ensure that '`Store`' Database is readable by the Cron command (for e.g. adding -U Postgres would be a good addition). If the DB login is dependent on .pgpass file, it wouldn't work with cron. In such scenarios, you'd need to ensure pg_hba.conf is configured for this purpose (for e.g. you could allow '`trust`' authentication for a specific-known DB / machine / user combination etc.
3. Ensure that /home/backups/postgres/... is accessible for writing, for obvious reasons.